# Creating a Radial basis function kernel matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning

I never used matlab, and I have this code about [kernalized locality sensitive functions](http://people.bu.edu/bkulis/klsh/klsh.htm).

I think that the following code is trying to create the kernalized matrix of a [RBF kernel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel):

```
%demo script for KLSH
X = load('iris.mtx');
...
[n,d] = size(X);

%form RBF over the data:
nms = sum(X'.^2);
K = exp(-nms'*ones(1,n) -ones(n,1)*nms + 2*X*X');
```

You can find the whole code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fv4e5ke0pxhs3qb/AAD6okqP_H7C6q7oHZIAMH_1a?dl=0) and in particular this code in [demo.m](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2dkjjt2t8957tsy/demo.m?dl=0).

Now, I cannot find the correlation of how `K` (the kernel matrix) is computed and the kernel function formula:

[image]

Can you help me to figure out how `K` is created (and explain me the code above) please?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690132/what-is-the-algorithm-for-an-rbf-kernel-matrix-in-matlab

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole trick is based on the fact that you want to compute matrix K_ij = K(x_i, x_j) = f(||x_i - x_j||^2) in an efficient manner. Matrix computations are based on dot products, thus multiplications, not on norm of a difference. If you do not want to use loops (and in languages like matlab or R you do not want to) you have to figure out how to express this ||x_i - x_j||^2 using matrix operations, thus:

```
||x_i - x_j||^2 = <x_i - x_j, x_i - x_j> 
                = <x_i, x_i> - <x_i, x_j> - <x_j, x_i> + <x_j, x_j>
                = ||x_i||^2 - 2<x_i, x_j> + ||x_j||^2
```

and this is exactly what is implemented

First they take square of your data, as ||x_i||^2 = SUM_a x_i_a^2

```
nms = sum(X'.^2);
```

next they use multiplication with vector of ones to compute the sum opertion getting

```
nms'*ones(1,n)
```

which is vector of ||x_i||^2's, and analogously vector of ||x_j||^2's is

```
ones(n,1)*nms
```

and finally they compose using decomposition I wrote before, thus

```
-nms'*ones(1,n) -ones(n,1)*nms + 2*X*X')
```

is just a matrix A_ij = - ||x_i - x_j ||^2

In your case, you want to have division by 2sigma^2, thus just put it under the exp, after taking previous arugment in brackets, like

```
Ks = exp(-(nms'*ones(1,n) -ones(n,1)*nms + 2*X*X')/(2*sigma^2));
```

Comment: Just one (probably dumb) question: why  ||x_i - x_j||^2 = <x_i - x_j, x_i - x_j> ?

Comment: this is (one of possible) definitions of norm `||a||^2 = SUM_i a_i^2 = SUM_i a_i * a_i = <a, a>`

Comment: The weird thing in this solution is that they eliminated the /(2*sigma^2)) part...even using sigma=1, it's still /2, which is not present. Well, anyway excellent answer, thanks :D

Comment: They assume sigma equal to 1/sqrt(2)